# PHP pass bool to PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I have a stored procedure in PostgreSQL declared like so:

```
IN ident_p int4, IN name_p varchar, IN email_p varchar, IN active_p bool, IN deleted_p bool
```

Then from PHP, I'm using the PDO library to call it.  I can't get the two bool parameters to take though.  I always get an error back saying no known function.  This is how I'm trying to call it.

```php
$st = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM create_or_update_producer(?::int4, ?::varchar, ?::varchar, ?::bool, ?::bool)');
$result = $st->execute([$ident, $name, $email, $active, $deleted]);
```

The server is running PHP 5.6.20 and PostgreSQL 9.1.21

Comment: Embarrassingly I found that my SQL editor was connected to a different datasource than my PHP files, and so it really didn't exist ;(